# How to do Specification Testing with ASP.NET MVC Error view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bdd

I'm doing BDD on an MVC3 project with SpecFlow. My current specification scenario says that:

```
Given a user is working on the system
When an error is raised
Then the user should be redirected to error page
And display a link to go back where he came from
```

How can I test a spec like this? I usually test the controller directly, however the Error view given by the standard MVC3 template has no controller, and no controller is used, because is redirected by the HandleError global filter.

In exceptional cases I use [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to test that the behavior conforms to what the specification says, however to do that I need a view that raises an error, something that when everything is working i do not have.

Any ideas on testing scenarios like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few thoughts on this scenario:

1.)  "Given a user is working on the system" is a pretty vague step.  What code would be found in the step definition?  Unless you have a user class that has a WorkingOnSystem method, it might be worth taking this line out.

2.)  Without having seen the rest of your code, I think the target of this feature should be the HandleError filter itself.  By its very definition, you know that when it is invoked an error has occurred.  All you need to do is instantiate the filter, call the appropriate method, and test the results.

Think about it this way:  What does "When an error is raised" mean in your system?  If your HandleError filter is not the place, then you probably don't have *a* place.  In which case, you'll need to be more specific.

---

I think the awkwardness around this spec is due to ASP.Net MVC.  When you're dealing with a framework of abstractions, you're sometimes left to "wrap" your specs around some part of it.  We just can't go end-to-end easily when the parts of the application come from so many places.

Comment: I totally agree, the specification is really vague. Following yogur brilliant advice about testing against the filter, should the spec stept start like this "Given an error has been occurred"?

Comment: I think in this case, if you write the tests against the handle error filter, you would want to state it as a When clause.  Like this:

When an error occurs on the site
Then the user should be redirected
And a log of the error should be made